# How to round float numbers in opencv with c++

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I want to round a float number ( or double) in opencv
I used this, but when debug with Qt I have it point at this line, so i was thinking that my code is fault:

```
j2 = round((theta/steptetha)+501);
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code? What are the input values and result of this line?

Comment: If "point at this line" means "compilation error": Did you include math.h or cmath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opencv round a double to it's nearest integer... but be careful if `theta` and `steptetha` are integer the division result is an integer... try something like:

```
j2 = round( ((double)theta/steptetha)+501.0);
```

now `((double)theta/steptetha)` will give a double